# Is it possible to migrate a SharePoint Server 2010 Farm to a new SharePoint 2013 Foundation?

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, migration

As title says, a client of ours wants to migrate a currently working SharePoint 2010 Server farm to a brand new farm running SharePoint Foundation 2013.

So, my questions are:

- Is it possible?
- Is there any downsides beyond few services not available in the Foundation 2013 version?
- If its possible, would the database attach method work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unsupported version of migration: [Review supported editions and products for upgrading to SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/b1088a52-179f-4120-8fb5-0ed3e6c088b1(v=office.16).aspx) Check under the "Supported cross-product upgrades"

but i think still it is possible.

- I would to create a new SharePoint Foundation 2010 farm.
- Now turn off all the SharePoint server 2010 related features in your current farm
- perform Content Database backup and restore it into SharePoint Foundation farm.
- Perform a complete test here and make sure everything is working.
- Now you can migrate from here to SharePoint 2013 foundation.

Alternate of this is use 3rd party tools and migrate from 2010 to 2013 foundation. you can try Sharegate or Metalogix (they offer free trial.) this is supported.

Answer (score 1):

I went through this before although it is an unsupported version of migration but I was able to successfully manage it.

1.Using Metalogix I was able to migrate all files to the Sharepoint 2013 without losing its metadata.

2.In SharePoint 2013 farm I created a new web application and stopped its database and then attached the SharePoint 2010 content database so all old files are in this web application in case i need any file later, but this web application is in old look and feel.

3.I turned off SharePoint 2010 farm and I used servers for playing GTA

I can go through it with you again for free just to remember old days (: